# VLCJ is not working correctly

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, vlcj

This is my first day with VLCJ. I downloaded the complete zip from [here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/downloads) and did the following to add it to my project in netbeans.

1. Create new project
2. Right click > Properties
3. Selected the VLCJ folder in "libraries" section.
4. Copied and pasted [this](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/tutorial2.php) code (second code)

Now, it is giving lot of compiler errors. It is telling that all the imported libraries are not available!!! What am I doing wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. I had to add the jar files directly. But I added the complete folder.